# Why the player is falling down through everything when using Animator to play Animation Clip?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Screenshots of the player (FPEPlayerController) inspector components and settings. The Animator is at the bottom in the second screenshot :

[image: Player Inspector]

[image: Player Inspector]

If i'm not checking the Apply Root Motion on the Animator it will not play the Animation Clip at all.
But even if not using Apply Root Motion the player is falling down the scene nonstop.
If not using the Animator component the player is stay fine. Once added the Animator the player is falling.

This is the Animator Controller settings screenshot :

[image: Animator Controller]

This is the Animation Clip settings screenshot :

[image: Animation Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check up "Is Kinematic" flag of RigidBody component. Maybe FPEPlayerController changes it.